# What is the reason of adding "Document.plainRandomAccess=true" before "reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(filenameSource),null)"?

Tags: java, file, pdf, itext, large-files

I am using itext 2.1.7 for processing large file of about 1.3gb. For that, I tried the following code to load the file:

```
Document.plainRandomAccess=true;
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new 
RandomAccessFileOrArray(filenameSource),null);
```

Please help me with the usage of `Document.plainRandomAccess=true`. Is there any repercussion of using or not using it any of the way? Is there any documentation which explains the same?

Answer (score 0):

From the [iText 5 Javadocs](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/5.5.13.1/com/itextpdf/text/Document.html#plainRandomAccess):

> `public static boolean plainRandomAccess`
>
> When true the file access is not done through a memory mapped file. Use it if the file is too big to be mapped in your address space.

From the [iText 7 Javadocs](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.11/com/itextpdf/io/source/RandomAccessFileOrArray.html#plainRandomAccess):

> `public static boolean plainRandomAccess`
>
> When true the file access is not done through a memory mapped file. Use it if the file is too big to be mapped in your address space.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: 'When true the file access is not done through a memory mapped file. Use it if the file is too big to be mapped in your address space.' - Can you please elaborate this answer? I saw it in the link before also, but didnt understand properly.